# Does the latest version of a plugin include snapshots?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

in the documentation of maven is written

> You'll notice that all plugins in Maven look much like a dependency -
>   and in some ways they are. This plugin will be automatically
>   downloaded and used - including a specific version if you request it
>   (**the default is to use the latest available**).

Source: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_plugins

Does "the default is to use the latest available" include snapshots or not?

Comment: In most cases, it is better to explicitly specify the version, e.g. in a parent pom. Otherwise you can get sudden build problems that do not stem from your code but from a silently updated plugin.

Comment: I would suggest to specify the version always....Furthermore SNAPSHOT versions of plugins are usually only for those who like to test plugins...but usually there is a VOTE on the dev mailing list to test versions of plugins but those are already releases See here: https://maven.apache.org/developers/release/maven-project-release-procedure.html

Comment: You are correct, best practice is to define exactly the required version, also do not use range like [2.0,)
I just like to understand what will be the result of "latest available"

Comment: I would not count on that. Simply define the version from this location: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html...